# Scraping a .txt table from a website after logging in using R

Tags: r, rvest, scrape

Ciao, I have access to a student server which I can not sure here for data security reasons. However I have found a website that features a similar style pop up. Basically I need to go to a URL, click a link to access data-this then brings a pop-up login box, then I need to get the data behind it. It looks similar to the attached image.[image] see there is no specific URL for login information thus I do not know how to redirect the URL with my login information. I did find code and I edited it but it doesn't hold the table that is needed. Lastly because I am not able to share the actual URL for security reasons I am troubled to make this replicatable. If you have advices I will honour them. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the content of the web page since you don't share the link. But what I understand from the picture is that, selenium web browser is what you are looking for. Search for selenium.(https://www.r-bloggers.com/scraping-with-selenium/)

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you use `html_form` and `submit_form` from the `rvest` package to login. Here is minimum example:

```
library(rvest)
# Establish first session connection
url <- "https://www.wesbite.co.uk" 
sp.session <- html_session(url)
fe         <- html_form(sp.session)

# Set values - manually
fe[[1]][["fields"]]$value <- "login details"

# Submit form and get new session
sp.session <- rvest::submit_form(sp.session, fe[[1]])
```